# What does the dualstack prefix mean in AWS ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

When I add an ELB as Alias Target in AWS Route 53, it automatically adds the `dualstack` prefix to my ELB DNS. What does this represent?

When I try `dig`, both returns the same endpoints.

Note: This is an internal load balancer.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The `dualstack` DNS name returns both IPv6 and IPv4 records for an **EC2-Classic** (Internet-facing, non-VPC) Elastic Load Balancer.

See the ELB documentation on [Internet-Facing Load Balancers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-internet-facing-load-balancers.html#internet-facing-ip-addresses):

> #### EC2-VPC
>
> Load balancers in a VPC support IPv4 addresses only. [...]
>
> #### EC2-Classic
>
> Load balancers in EC2-Classic support both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. [...]
>
> The base public DNS name returns only IPv4 records. The public DNS name with the `ipv6` prefix returns only IPv6 records. The public DNS name with the `dualstack` prefix returns both IPv4 and IPv6 records. We recommend that you enable IPv6 support by using the DNS name with the `dualstack` prefix to ensure that clients can access the load balancer using either IPv4 or IPv6.

Although the Route53 console *always* prepends `dualstack.` to the DNS name when choosing an Alias Target for an `A` (IPv4) or `AAAA` (IPv6) Resource Record Set (as noted in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-alias.html#rrsets-values-alias-alias-target)), and additionally the `dualstack.*` endpoint always correctly returns an IPv4 `A` record, *only* the DNS names for an **EC2-Classic** ELB (either the `dualstack.*` or `ipv6.*` endpoint) currently return IPv6 `AAAA` records, or serve as a valid alias target for an `AAAA` record.

You can confirm using `dig`:

```
dig dualstack.[endpoint] A dualstack.[endpoint] AAAA +short
```

Only an EC2-Classic ELB will return both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses for this command, the others will only return an IPv4 address.

Comment: Technically, as the question is in relation to aliases, it will only return IPv6 answers if you also create an AAAA alias as well.

Comment: Any idea if the above answer is valid for internal load balancers also?

Comment: @NithinSatheesan added more info, clarifying that the IPv6 dualstack endpoint is only useful for EC2-Classic Elastic Load Balancers not in a VPC.

Comment: @NithinSatheesan - its only useful for internet facing

Comment: AWS VPCs and ALBs support ipv6 now.