# Why use dualstack elb aws

Tags: ip, amazon-elb

There is a post on what is dualstack aws elb.

[link to what is dualstack elb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623388/what-does-the-dualstack-prefix-mean-in-aws-elb)

I can't understand why bother since Route53 does the job?

Comment: What do you mean by "since Route53 does the job"?

Comment: Although the Route53 console always prepends dualstack.....etc did i miss smth in that long line. check it in the link I provided.